# Why vue computed property doesn't become reaective?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, computed-properties

Some part of my script setup:

```js
    const storyVideo = ref("storyVideo")
    const topBar = computed(() => {
        return 'background-position: ' + (storyVideo?.value?.currentTime / store.instagram.story[store
            .currentStory].duration) * 100 + '% 0;'
    })
```

`storyVideo` is a `video` element with `ref="storyVideo"` and `store` points to Pinia store

I assigned it to an element using `:style="topBar"`

The element style is always `background-position: 0% 0;` but the variables used in the function change

I tried to log what is returned in this function using a `@click` and `console.log` and everything looks properly in logs:

```css
background-position: 9.07100199071002% 0;
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? It would be useful if you provide the change of the variables used in the function

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your trying to access the element too early, check the documentation https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#accessing-the-refs

> Note that you can only access the ref after the component is mounted.
> If you try to access input in a template expression, it will be null
> on the first render. This is because the element doesn't exist until
> after the first render!
>
> If you are trying to watch the changes of a template ref, make sure to
> account for the case where the ref has null value: